Laravel validation distinct only for its siblings array element
We have this validation code:
$data = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [3, 4, 5]
];

$validator = \Validator::make([
    "bla" => $data,
], [
    'bla'           => 'required|array', 
    'bla.*'         => 'required|array|max:5|min:1',
    'bla.*.*'       => 'required|integer|distinct',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {...}

As you can see, we added distinct on the inner array. Currently, this code is getting an error:
The bla.0.2 field has a duplicate value.
The bla.1.0 field has a duplicate value.

What we are trying to achieve is only check if there is a duplicate on inner array. In this example, since all the inner arrays are unique, it should pass the validation.
distinct seems to check everything. including other inner arrays.
Example:
This should pass:
$data = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [3, 4, 5]
];

This should not pass since there are 2 4s on the first inner array.
$data = [
    [4, 4, 3],
    [3, 8, 5]
];

Any help would be appreaciated.

Do you want to check the integer values with the min/max constraint, or the sub-array length?

@Olivier the min max is for the number of array elements.

For some reason distinct checks all of the sub-arrays
so to fix that you could fix it by write custom validation rule like this one
$data = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [3, 4, 5]
];

$validator = Validator::make([
    "bla" => $data,
], [
    'bla'           => 'required|array',
    'bla.*'         => [
        'required',
        'array',
        'max:5',
        'min:1',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if (count($value) !== count(array_unique($value))) {
                $fail($attribute . ' contains duplicate values.');
            }
        }
    ],
    'bla.*.*'       => ['required', 'integer'],
]);


I don't think so, because he add this min and max to the sub-array itself to control it's length not the number itself

by the end of the day this is not the issue that he asked for help for, his issue is about the duplicates only

You can use 'after' to check for duplicates in each inner array, Like
$validator->after(function ($validator) use ($data) {
        foreach ($data as $index => $innerArray) {
            if (count($innerArray) !== count(array_unique($innerArray))) {
                $validator->errors()->add("bla.$index", "The elements in bla.$index must be distinct.");
            }
       }
  });

